# detect git branch in Vagrantfile and use it to control vm provisioning script, host only network ip address, etc

Tags: git, vagrant

I have a bit of a peculiar situation in my company where we have one giant git repository containing all of our code.

It is very difficult to separate the code into libraries and modules in the short term.

But we would like to "generate" servers based on roles that the code is supposed to play, for example, website, soap web service, rest web service, etc.

One idea is to use git branches to signal the variations. The code will be mostly identical but the config files that control server behaviour will be different.

I wrote this into our bash provisioning script and it works.

I am now looking to see if Vagrant supports such a scheme.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to implement the switching logic yourself, but it should be fairly trivial.

Somewhere (probably before the `configure` block) you'll want to work out what the current branch is:

```
branch = `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
```

Then, use this however you require inside your box definition(s). For example, you may switch provisioners based on the branch:

```
# snip
shell_provisioner = case branch
                    when 'master'  then 'path/to/provisioner.sh'
                    when 'widgets' then 'path/to/widgets.sh'
end

config.vm.provision :shell, path: shell_provisioner
```

This is infinitely flexible, and depends what you actually want to vary based on the branch. I'm happy to expand this if needed.

Comment: Thanks Lewis. Let me try this. I think you also improved on the git command I used for branch detection. I was using something like 'git branch | awk...'

Comment: The only caveat to `rev-parse` is that it won't return a useful result if you're in a detached head state, but will instead return `HEAD`. If this is common in your workflow you may have to find another way - as it's quite hard in general to work out which branch a detached HEAD "belongs to".

Comment: I don't know much about detached head states but are you saying that in a detached head situation, a 'git branch | awk ...' style command will still work to identify the branch?

Comment: It only means that you're on a branch, but not at the HEAD. (You can see this by "going back" a commit on your branch `git checkout HEAD~1`). If you use `git branch | awk ...` you'll just get `* detached from <hash>)` instead of a branch name, so it isn't any better in those cases